# Create XML based on text tree

Tags: c#, xml, linq, tree

I need to go from a list like this:

```
/home
/home/room1
/home/room1/subroom
/home/room2
/home/room2/miniroom
/home/room2/bigroom
/home/room2/hugeroom
/home/room3
```

to an xml file. I've tried using LINQ to XML to do this but I just end up getting confused and not sure what to do from there. Any help is much appreciated!

Edit:

I want the XML file to look something like this:

```
<home>
   <room1>
      <subroom>This is a subroom</subroom>
   </room1>
   <room2>
      <miniroom>This is a miniroom</miniroom>
      <bigroom>This is a bigroom</bigroom>
      <hugeroom>This is a hugeroom</hugeroom>
   </room2>
   <room3></room3>
</home>
```

The text inside if the tags ("this is a subroom", etc) is optional, but would be really nice to have!

Comment: And how do you want the xml to look like?

Comment: I'll post it in my original post. Sorry.

Comment: Edit your question and place in there "This is how my XML should look like: [ your desired XML result ]"

Comment: I've placed it into my original post.

Comment: Ok, where in your text is "this is a subroom" (or miniroom, etc) - where does that come from?

Comment: It's just "This is a" + name of the node. So, for subroom it was "This is a subroom", for bigroom it is "This is a bigroom", and so on.

Comment: Are you sure there will always be only 3 levels in your input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok buddy, here's a solution.

**Couple of notes and explanation.**

Your text structure can be split up into lines and then again by the slashes into the names of the XML nodes. If you think of the text in this way, you get a list of "lines" broken into a list of 
names.

```
/home
```

First of all, the first line `/home` is the root of the XML; we can get rid of it and just create and XDocument object with that name as the root element;

```
var xDoc = new XDocument("home");
```

Of course we don't want to hard code things but this is just an example. Now, on to the real work:

```
/home/room1/
/home/room1/bigroom
etc...
```

as a `List<T>` then it will look like this

```
myList = new List<List<string>>();
... [ add the items ]
myList[0][0] = home
myList[0][1] = room1

myList[1][0] = home
myList[1][1] = room1
myList[1][2] = bigroom
```

So what we can do to get the above structure is use `string.Split()` multiple times to break your text first into lines, then into parts of each line, and end up with a multidimensional array-style `List<T>` that contains `List<T>` objects, in this case, `List<List<string>>`.

First let's create the container object:

```
var possibleNodes = new List<List<string>>();
```

Next, we should split the lines. Let's call the variable that holds the text, "text".

```
var splitLines = text
    .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList();
```

This gives us a List but our lines are still not broken up. Let's split them again by the slash (`/`) character. This is where we build our node names. We can do this in a ForEach and just add to our list of possible nodes:

```
splitLines.ForEach(l => 
    possibleNodes.Add(l
        .Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .ToList()
    )
);
```

Now, we need to know the DEPTH of the XML. Your text shows that there will be 3 nodes of depth. The node depth is the maximum depth of any one given line of nodes, now stored in the `List<List<string>>`; we can use the `.Max()` method to get this:

```
var nodeDepth = possibleNodes.Max(n => n.Count);
```

A final setup step: We don't need the first line, because it's just "home" and it will be our root node. We can just create an `XDocument` object and give it this first line to use as the name of `Root`:

```
// Create the root node
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement(possibleNodes[0][0]));

// We don't need it anymore
possibleNodes.RemoveAt(0);
```

Ok, here is where the real work happens, let me explain the rules:

1. We need to loop through the outer list, and through each inner list.
2. We can use the list indexes to understand which node to add to or which names to ignore
3. We need to keep hierarchy proper and not duplicate nodes, and some XLinq helps here

The loops - see the comments for a detailed explanation:

```
// This gets us looping through the outer nodes
for (var i = 0; i < possibleNodes.Count; i++) 
{
    // Here we go "sideways" by going through each inner list (each broken down line of the text)
    for (var ii = 1; ii < nodeDepth; ii++)
    {
        // Some lines have more depth than others, so we have to check this here since we are looping on the maximum
        if (ii < possibleNodes[i].Count)
        {
            // Let's see if this node already exists
            var existingNode = xDoc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName == (possibleNodes[i][ii]));

            // Let's also see if a parent node was created in the previous loop iteration. 
            // This will tell us whether to add the current node at the root level, or under another node
            var parentNode = xDoc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName == (possibleNodes[i][ii - 1]));

            // If the current node has already been added, we do nothing (this if statement is not entered into)
            // Otherwise, existingNode will be null and that means we need to add the current node
            if (null == existingNode)
            {
                // Now, use parentNode to decide where to add the current node
                if (null == parentNode)
                {
                    // The parent node does not exist; therefore, the current node will be added to the root node.
                    xDoc.Root.Add(new XElement(possibleNodes[i][ii]));
                }
                else
                {
                    // There IS a parent node for this node! 
                    // Therefore, we must add the current node to the parent node 
                    // (remember, parent node is the previous iteration of the inner for loop on nodeDepth )
                    var newNode = new XElement(possibleNodes[i][ii]);
                    parentNode.Add(newNode);

                    // Add "this is a" text (bonus!) -- only adding this text if the current node is the last one in the list.
                    if (possibleNodes[i].Count -1 == ii)
                    {
                        newNode.Add(new XText("This is a " + newNode.Name.LocalName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bonus here is this code will work with any number of nodes and build your XML.

To check it, `XDocument` has a nifty `.ToString()` overriden implementation that just spits out all of the XML it is holding, so all you do is this:

```
Console.Write(xDoc.ToString());
```

And, you'll get this result: 
(Note I added a test node to make sure it works with more than 3 levels)

[image]

**Below, you will find the entire program with your test text, etc, as a working solution:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlFromTextString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This simulates text from a file; note that it must be flush to the left of the screen or else the extra spaces 
            // add unneeded nodes to the lists that are generated; for simplicity of code, I chose not to implement clean-up of that and just 
            // ensure that the string literal is not indented from the left of the Visual Studio screen.
            string text =
@"/home
/home/room1
/home/room1/subroom
/home/room2
/home/room2/miniroom
/home/room2/test/thetest
/home/room2/bigroom
/home/room2/hugeroom
/home/room3";

            var possibleNodes = new List<List<string>>();

            var splitLines = text
                .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .ToList();

            splitLines.ForEach(l => 
                possibleNodes.Add(l
                    .Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .ToList()
                )
            );

            var nodeDepth = possibleNodes.Max(n => n.Count);

            // Create the root node
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement(possibleNodes[0][0]));

            // We don't need it anymore
            possibleNodes.RemoveAt(0);

            // This gets us looping through the outer nodes
            for (var i = 0; i < possibleNodes.Count; i++)  
            {
                // Here we go "sideways" by going through each inner list (each broken down line of the text)
                for (var ii = 1; ii < nodeDepth; ii++)
                {
                    // Some lines have more depth than others, so we have to check this here since we are looping on the maximum
                    if (ii < possibleNodes[i].Count)
                    {
                        // Let's see if this node already exists
                        var existingNode = xDoc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName == (possibleNodes[i][ii]));

                        // Let's also see if a parent node was created in the previous loop iteration. 
                        // This will tell us whether to add the current node at the root level, or under another node
                        var parentNode = xDoc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName == (possibleNodes[i][ii - 1]));

                        // If the current node has already been added, we do nothing (this if statement is not entered into)
                        // Otherwise, existingNode will be null and that means we need to add the current node
                        if (null == existingNode)
                        {
                            // Now, use parentNode to decide where to add the current node
                            if (null == parentNode)
                            {
                                // The parent node does not exist; therefore, the current node will be added to the root node.
                                xDoc.Root.Add(new XElement(possibleNodes[i][ii]));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // There IS a parent node for this node! 
                                // Therefore, we must add the current node to the parent node 
                                // (remember, parent node is the previous iteration of the inner for loop on nodeDepth )
                                var newNode = new XElement(possibleNodes[i][ii]);
                                parentNode.Add(newNode);

                                // Add "this is a" text (bonus!) -- only adding this text if the current node is the last one in the list.
                                if (possibleNodes[i].Count -1 == ii)
                                {
                                    newNode.Add(new XText("This is a " + newNode.Name.LocalName));
                                    // For the same default text on all child-less nodes, us this:
                                    // newNode.Add(new XText("This is default text"));

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.Write(xDoc.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you're ignoring from the last node (room3): `var i = 1; i < possibleNodes.Count - 1; i++`?

Comment: Fixed now I just noticed that too

Comment: My apologizes about the late response, but this works absolutely perfectly. Thank you so much, and thank you for the detailed response. This really helps a lot.

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to edit it so that everything without a child gets the same default text, any advice?

Comment: @user3258945: See update in the bottom of my answer (in a comment) .. The only things without a child are the same nodes that have "This is a ..." in them ... if you want the text to be the same, remove + newNode.Name.LocalName from that line, and change "This is a" to the default text you want.

Answer (score 3):

Time for LINQ magic?

```
// load file into string[]
var input = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt");

// in case you have more than one home in your file
var homes =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement("root",
             from line in input
             let items = line.Split(new[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             group items by items[0] into g
             select new XElement(g.Key,
                 from rooms in g.OrderBy(x => x.Length).Skip(1)
                 group rooms by rooms[1] into g2
                 select new XElement(g2.Key,
                     from name in g2.OrderBy(x => x.Length).Skip(1)
                     select new XElement(name[2], string.Format("This is a {0}", name[2]))))));

// get the right home
var home = new XDocument(homes.Root.Element("home"));
```